# Eloquent ORM Dynamic Where - Is there a shortcut / more elegant solution?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

Is there a more elegant / better solution to the below code? At present, I have to repeat a lot of query just to add an extra 'where' into the query.

```
    if ($common == true) {
        $products = self::with(array(
               'metal', 
               'metal.fixes.currency', 
               'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id){
                   $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
               }))
           ->where('metal_id', '=', $metal_id)
           ->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type_id)
           ->where('common', '=', 1) // This line is the only difference 
                                            between the two Queries
           ->get();           
    }
    else {
        $products = self::with(array(
            'metal', 
            'metal.fixes.currency', 
            'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id){
                $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
            }))
        ->where('metal_id', '=', $metal_id)
        ->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type_id)
        ->get();
    }
```

Comment: This would be more suitable at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly why are you doing `$common == true`?

Secondly you don't need to do all building at once, here is how you can do it.

**PHP 5.3**

```
$products = $this->with(
     array('metal', 
           'metal.fixes.currency', 
           'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id)
           {
                $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
           }))
          ->where('metal_id', $metal_id)
          ->where('product_type_id', $product_type_id);

if ($common)
{
    $products->where('common', 1);
}

$products = $products->get();
```

**PHP 5.4**

```
$products = $this->with(
          ['metal', 
           'metal.fixes.currency', 
           'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id)
           {
                $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
           }])
          ->where('metal_id', $metal_id)
          ->where('product_type_id', $product_type_id);

if ($common)
{
    $products->where('common', 1);
}

$products = $products->get();
```

Could be formatted better but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for this. $common == true was just written to illustrate the question.

Comment: I tried this method before, but had problems chaining. I was trying to chain another ->where when I already used ->get() method

Answer (score 0):

Sinque Eloquent/QueryBuilder always return a reference to itself you can write a more elegant version as follow:

```php
$query = self::with(array(
               'metal', 
               'metal.fixes.currency', 
               'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id){
                   $query->where('currency_id', $currency_id);
               }))
           ->where('metal_id', $metal_id)
           ->where('product_type_id', $product_type_id)

if ($common) {
    $query = query->where('common', 1);        
}

$products = $query->get();
```

Comment: $query = query->where('common', '=', 1); should just be $query->where('common', '=', 1); don't need to apply like that when chaining

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
$products = self::with(array(
               'metal', 
               'metal.fixes.currency', 
               'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id){
                   $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
               }))
           ->where('metal_id', '=', $metal_id)
           ->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type_id)
           ->where('common', '=', (int)$common) // This line is the only difference 
                                            between the two Queries
           ->get();           
}
```

That way you do not need the if. If you must you do not care about the common flag

```
$products = self::with(array(
               'metal', 
               'metal.fixes.currency', 
               'metal.fixes' => function($query) use ($currency_id){
                   $query->where('currency_id', '=', $currency_id);
               }))
           ->where('metal_id', '=', $metal_id)
           ->where('product_type_id', '=', $product_type_id);

$products = ($common) ? $products->where('common', 1)->get() : $products->get();
```